# Highchart graph not displaying via Django

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I've been trying to display a Highchart graph via Django, but in vain. See below, the hmtl code I get from the *view source* mode from my browser... The graph dataset is passed on nicely and shows up in the code, but the graph doesn't show up on the page and I get no errors from the javascript console.

What am I missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Highcharts- Demo</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left:40px;
        }
                pre {
        border:1px solid red;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 800px; margin: 2em auto; padding: 1em; border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 0.5em">
    Nicely plotted data in Highcharts.
      </div>
    <div id="chart_ID" class="chart" style="height:600px; width:100%">
    </div>

<!-- Maps the Python template context variables from views.py to the Highchart js variables -->
<script>
    var chart_id = "chart_ID"
    var chart = {"renderTo": "chart_ID", "type": "line", "height": 500}
    var title = {"text": "my title goes here"}
    var xAxis = {"categories": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"], "title": {"text": "Axis title goes here"}}
    var yAxis = {"title": {"text": "Axis title goes here"}}
    var series = [{"data": [1, NaN, 2, 3, NaN, 4, 5], "name": "Asia Pacific"}, {"data": [1, NaN, 2, 3, NaN, 4, 5], "name": "CIS"}, {"data": [1, NaN, 2, 3, NaN, 4, 5], "name": "Europe"}, {"data": [1, NaN, 2, 3, NaN, 4, 5], "name": "Latin America"}, {"data": [1, NaN, 2, 3, NaN, 4, 5], "name": "MENA"}, {"data": [1, NaN, 2, 3, NaN, 4, 5], "name": "Northern America"}, {"data": [1, NaN, 2, 3, NaN, 4, 5], "name": "SSA"}]
</script>

<!-- Highchart js. Variable map shown above -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(chart_id).highcharts({
        chart: chart,
        title: title,
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        series: series
    });
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) This line has a typo:

```
var xAxis = {"categories": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", G"], "title": {"text": "Axis title goes here"}}
```

It should be:

```
var xAxis = {"categories": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"], "title": {"text": "Axis title goes here"}}
```

2) You need to prepend a `#` to your `chart_id` in order for jQuery to find it:

```
var chart_id = "#chart_ID"
```

Making both these changes causes your example to work.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much, I've been scratching my head on that one for so long, much appreciated!